# Draw box around paragraph with swift

Tags: ios, swift

i want to create a view or textview like this box.
I already try to create html with div as nsattributedtext but i can't set the border for the paragraph

`<div style='background-color:#4fa5d5; color:white; font-weight: bold'>title</div><div style='border: 5px solid black;'><p style='margin-left: 5px'>content</p></div>`

any suggestion ?

[image: I want to make a view like this image]

Comment: do you want the text to be editable?

Comment: no..i just want read only text

Comment: are you using a webview? don't you want to build this using native views?

Comment: no, currently i'm using text view. and i just render all text to this textview, but i need some part of them to be render like that box.
And i'm okay if the native views can render like that.

Comment: Do you have the layout setup? You should be using UIViews an UILabels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating 2 UILabels in the user interface, one on top of another. Constraint them to their positions. Then add this extension:

```
extension UILabel {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
       var bounds: CGRect = self.bounds
       var maskPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(radius, radius))
       var maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
       maskLayer.frame = bounds
       maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
       self.layer.mask = maskLayer
       var frameLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
       frameLayer.frame = bounds
       frameLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
       frameLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
       frameLayer.fillColor = nil
       self.layer.addSublayer(frameLayer)
   }
}
```

Then round the top corners of the top label

```
topLabel.roundCorners(UIRectCorner.TopLeft, radius: 10)
topLabel.roundCorners(UIRectCorner.TopRight, radius: 10)
```

Then round the bottom corners of the bottom label

```
bottomLabel.roundCorners(UIRectCorner.BottomLeft, radius: 10)
bottomLabel.roundCorners(UIRectCorner.BottomRight, radius: 10)
```

Lastly, add a border:

```
for label in [topLabel, bottomLabel] {
    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor.CGColor
    label.layer.borderWidth = 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion..
I just use textView right now so it can be selectable :)

Comment: @cana Does it work for you?